# Unable to save and retrieve using ByteAarrayOutputStream

Tags: java, java-me, rms

I am making this J2ME application but I am having some problem when I am trying to save I thinks that it save properly but I am not sure....but when I retrieve it gives null

This is how I am storing them

```
        PAR par = new PAR(oldMonPay, newMonPay, oldInterest);
        par.setOldMPay(oldMonPay);
        par.setNewMPay(newMonPay);
        par.setOldInt(oldInterest);
```

And this is how I saving and retrieving

```
public static byte[] parseObjPAR(PAR p) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream out;

    try {
        out = new DataOutputStream(baos);
        out.writeUTF(p.getNewMPay());
        out.writeUTF(p.getOldInt());
        out.writeUTF(p.getOldMPay());



    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    return baos.toByteArray();
}

public static PAR parseByteArrPAR(byte[] b) {
    PAR p = null;
    ByteArrayInputStream bais;
    DataInputStream in;

    if (b != null) {
        try {
            bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
            in = new DataInputStream(bais);
            p = new PAR(
                    in.readUTF(),
                    in.readUTF(),
                    in.readUTF());    
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
    return p;
}
```

This is how I displaying the retrieved information, there is another problem this thing is not showing all the data but is only showing the 3 records. I think the first 3.

```
 public void populatePAResult(PAR[] p) {
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
            String oldMP = p[i].getOldMPay();
            String newMP = p[i].getNewMPay();
            String oldI = p[i].getOldInt();



            result1.append("Day : " + oldMP, null);
            result1.append("Time : " + oldI, null);
            result1.append("Technology : " + newMP, null);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are seeing?  It would help to know!

Comment: Suggest you properly implement exception handling in your read/write methods - you are silently ignoring any I/O errors which I suspect would help, at least dump the stack-trace to the console.

Comment: Well it doesnot stores the value I think, When I am calling that string value it gives null..

Comment: Which string value are you referring to?  Are you getting an exception? or is it just not working as expected?

Comment: Also the order you write the `PAR` data in your `parseObjPAR` method is different to the order in the constructor used in `parseByteArrPAR`.

Comment: no its working the values that i am saving, I am retrieving the same values when I run the application again, but it gives back null no exception .

Comment: and can you plz tell what order are you talking about it looks fine to me

Comment: `populatePAResult` does not populate anything.  It just prints stuff.  So what I think is going on is that you are printing out a `PAR[]` that you haven't actually populated ... or you have populated incorrectly.  You need to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question so that we can **see** what you are actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

In the `parseObjPAR` method that writes the data the order is:

```
out.writeUTF(p.getNewMPay());
out.writeUTF(p.getOldInt());
out.writeUTF(p.getOldMPay());
```

whereas when you read it back in and pass the order the constructor is expecting is different:

```
PAR par = new PAR(oldMonPay, newMonPay, oldInterest);
```

so even if it wasn't `null` the loaded data would be invalid.

Comment: Ok I fixed this so now I have to clear the previous data ? because it is giving the null again..can you please check my question again i have edited it